# Debugging TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2008, exception

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 (C# Express Edition) and I'm trying to debug a TargetInvocationException that occurs as a result of an event that I trigger.

[image]

My question isn't specificly about this exception, (hence why I've not included any detail about this exception), but more about using the IDE effectively to debug this.

I can see the inner exception gives me the detail I need to debug the error (clicking on 'View Detail' in the exception helper), but being fairly lazy, or should I say, trying to make good use of the tools I have at my disposal, I'd like to be able to convince the IDE to show me the exception helper for original (Inner Exception) within my code for the correct thread, complete with stack trace, rather than showing me the exception details for the calling thread.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried checking option  - `break on CLR exceptions` in exceptions dialog box?

Comment: @RohitVats Where do I find that option, bearing in mind I'm using express edition?

Comment: `Debug -> Exceptions`

Comment: @RohitVats That works, many thanks. Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tell debugger to break on `CLR exception` so that you can see the exact place where it is throwing exception.

You can check it under `Debug -> Exceptions`.

You can find it here -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exception Assistant Dialog Box might help you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ww37f14.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but the exception assistant (exception helper in VS 2008) is what I'm using, it's in the image in my question.

Comment: Usually the exception details are shown in the output console when Exception Assistant kicks in.